# Javascript for loop syntax refresher and function

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I am making this "game". I use quotes because it's not much of a game at all. This is in javascript. I need to make a for loop that calls a function which decreases a variable. This function should run until the predefined value = 0. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var counter=10;                      //create counter (+1)
function myFunction(){ counter--; }  //function that decreases counter
for(; counter; myFunction());        //while counter > 0, execute function
```

Comment: Thank you. I just needed a verbal explanation to refresh my memory. This is great.

Comment: you are very welcome. Sometimes a simple snippet is better then a thousand words!